# how would i write a HTML/CSS/JS code that generates a 3d spinning cube?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been recently making my own website, and I decided that I want to have a 3d cube effect that would spin around clockwise; I wrote some of the basic codes down but when I am getting to the CSS part the whole construction decides to give up on me and do stuff I did not mean for it to do.

I am fairly new to HTML and CSS, so I don't know everything about this. This is the code I've written so far, a bit of a warning to this is that I do not know how to code in JavaScript.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: lime;
  font-family: "Courier New";
}

.cube {
  perspective: 800px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  text-align: center;
}

.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid lime;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}

.front {
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.top {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.right {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="cube">
  <div class="face front">1</div>
  <div class="face back">2</div>
  <div class="face top">3</div>
  <div class="face bottom">4</div>
  <div class="face left">5</div>
  <div class="face right">6</div>
</div>
```

The biggest problem for me was actually centering the cube, I tried margins and flexbox but I really am not sure what I'm doing wrong. If anyone would be okay with helping me, I would be grateful.

Comment: Do you have a reference video of how it should rotate?